# javascript code work in firefox and chrome but not in safari and IE explorer

Tags: javascript

i have below javascript code that evaluate time span between two dates as below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(

function () {


    setInterval(function () {
        var date1 = new Date();
        var date2 = new Date("30/Feb/2017 07:07:07");

        var diff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());

        var days = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        diff -= days * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
        if (days < 10)
            days = "0" + days;
        var hours = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        diff -= hours * (1000 * 60 * 60);
        if (hours < 10)
            hours = "0" + hours;
        var mins = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60));

        diff -= mins * (1000 * 60);
        if (mins < 10)
            mins = "0" + mins;
        var seconds = Math.floor(diff / (1000));
        if (seconds < 10)
            seconds = "0" + seconds;
        diff -= seconds * (1000);
        var time = days + " روز, " + hours + " ساعت, " + mins + " دقیقه, " + seconds + " ثانیه";
        document.getElementById("remaingTimeDays").textContent = days;
        document.getElementById("remaingTimeHours").textContent = hours;
        document.getElementById("remaingTimeMinutes").textContent = mins;
        document.getElementById("remaingTimeSeconds").textContent = seconds;
    }, 1000);
});
```

this code works fine in Firefox and Chrome but is not working in Safari, IE and Edge.
I almost read all questions about the topic but I did not find any appropriate solution.

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: no error. in safari and IE it returns Nan

Comment: Needs more [mcve].

Comment: just put some effort in debugging it. log some variables and see what's going on.

Comment: 30 February? ok

Comment: I make it 29 Feb. but doesnot work

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that I write the due date in incorrect format.
the correct format is as below:

```
var date2 = new Date("02/30/2017 07:07:07");
```

02: is month
30: is day
2017: year and so on. thanks to all my friend to help correct this problem. thank you all guys very much